# ExcelDNA Dynamically Registering UDF at Runtime

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-interop, excel-dna

My aim is to dynamically build and register an Excel user defined function at runtime in an ExcelDNA AddIn.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/govert/1378887) provided by the ExcelDNA author which highlights how you can compile a UDF from a simple C# code string.

As you can see, this code is executed by calling `RegisterMyClass`from within the AddIn's `AutoOpen` method; and everything works perfectly.

However, if you move the `RegisterMyClass` method into (for example) a Ribbon button's action method, the registration of the dynamic UDF does not work and results in the following error:

```
Registration [Error] xlfRegister call failed for function or command: 'MyDynamicAdd'
```

In fact, it seems like any calls to `ExcelIntegration.RegisterMethods` fail in the above error message - unless they are called from within the `AutoOpen` method.

### My question is:

> How can I dynamically register a new UDF at runtime and triggered by a click on a Ribbon button?

#### Referenced Gist code for completeness' sake:

```
<DnaLibrary Name="ExcelDna Test Dynamic Method" Language="C#">
<Reference Name="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <![CDATA[
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.CSharp;
    using ExcelDna.Integration;

    public class Test : IExcelAddIn
    {
        // Just to test that we are loaded.
        public static double MyAdd(double d1, double d2)
        {
            return d1 + d2;
        }

        public void AutoOpen()
        {
            RegisterMyClass();
        }

        public void AutoClose()
        {
        }

        private void RegisterMyClass()
        {
            string code = 
                @"
                public class Script 
                { 
                    public static double MyDynamicAdd(double d1, double d2)
                    {
                        return d1 + d2;
                    }
                }";

        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll"); //, "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "ExcelDna.Integration.dll" );
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, new string[] { code });
        if (!cr.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            Assembly asm = cr.CompiledAssembly;
            Type[] types = asm.GetTypes();
            List<MethodInfo> methods = new List<MethodInfo>();

            // Get list of MethodInfo's from assembly for each method with ExcelFunction attribute
            foreach (Type type in types)
            {
                foreach (MethodInfo info in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
                {
                    methods.Add(info);
                }
            }
            Integration.RegisterMethods(methods);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errors during compile!");
        }
    }
    }
]]>
</DnaLibrary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to register the function needs to be in a context where the C API is available. It won't work in a ribbon callback or any other COM event handler.

One option to switch into a macro context where the C API is available is to call the `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro` helper, and run the registration code in the delegate you pass in.